# How do you configure the XCode Jenkins plugin to run tests?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The instructions for running tests with the Jenkins XCode plugin say to set the test target (which I've done), the SDK (which I've done) and the configuration (which I tried with nothing, Debug, and Test).

However I keep getting "...is not configured for running".

How do I actually get it to run tests?

This is the output:

```
+ xcodebuild -workspace /Users/MyDir/.Jenkins/jobs/MyTests/workspace/folder/MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyTestScheme clean
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace MyWorkspace with scheme MyTestScheme.
    Reason: Scheme "MyTestScheme" is not configured for running.
```

If within XCode for MyTestScheme if I choose Product/Run then I get the same error message, but if I choose  Product/Test then the test code executes successfully. The output from a sucessful run in Xcode is:

```
2013-08-28 11:10:25.828 otest[65917:303] Unknown Device Type. Using UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone based on screen size
Test Suite 'Multiple Selected Tests' started at 2013-08-28 18:10:26 +0000
Test Suite '/Users/MyDir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyWorkspace-ctngidolzdhijvbymvghygtoaiiw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyTestScheme.octest(Tests)' started at 2013-08-28 18:10:26 +0000
Test Suite 'MyTests' started at 2013-08-28 18:10:26 +0000
Test Case '-[MyTests test1]' started.
2013-08-28 11:10:26.029 otest[65917:303] MDN: (null)
Test Case '-[MyTests testA1]' passed (0.346 seconds).
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was using the test schema. The debug schema should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

XCode plugin maintainer here. I don't know the answer, but I would love to help you out.

Have you tried fiddling with the destination argument ?

E.g. `-destination 'OS=8.0,name=iPhone'`
or `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.0,name=iPhone 6s'`

(adjust depending on your needs)

If that doesn't work, please try to copy the output generated by the run of the tests from XCode itself.

Comment: Hello. Is the destination a setting in the Xcode Jenkins plugin? If so I cannot see it anywhere. In case its the custom xcodebuild arguments section you are referring to I tried that but without success. I've added the output to my posting.

Comment: Again please copy the output of the successful xcode run. You are missing some arguments to properly trigger the test scheme

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to use the -destination argument witht he plugin? I have attempted to add it to my jenkinsfile but got an error "WorkflowScript: 162: Invalid parameter "destination", did you mean "configuration"?"

Answer (score 2):

To configure the Xcode plugin for unit testing you need to write "test" in the "Custom xcodebuild arguments" field inside the "Advanced Xcode build options".